# If a 3x3 matrix multiplied with a 3x3 matrix returns the transform of the second 3x3 matrix, what does a nonsquare matrix multiplied with 3x3 return?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have just recently been introduced to matrices. What Ive understood for example, is that a 3x3 matrix can be thought of as a vector, the first column representing the x component/ x axis basis, second column the y component/y axis basis and so on.

So a 3x3 matrix multiplied with a 3x3 matrix returns us a matrix where the vectors of the second 3x3 matrix have been transformed by the first 3x3 matrix.

This makes sense, the x-component of the first matrix is treated as basis and the x coordinate of each of the x y and z components of the second matrix is transformed as per the basis we got from the first matrix, rinse repeat for the rest of the second matrix

But for something like say  2x4 matrix **A** multiplied with a 2x2 matrix **B**, how can the same logic be applied in the same intuitive manner?

Matrix **A** is a vector containing 4 components in the x y z axis and whatever the 4th axis is, and each of these components have 2 coordinates x and y.

Matrix **B** on the other hand has 2 components X and Y, each with x and y coordinates for that specific component

When A transforms B, how would the Z component of A transform matrix B if B has no Z component at all? Similarly how does the 4th "dimension"'s component  transform B if it doesn't have that component?

Not to mention , the Z and 4th dimension's components themselves are only represented by 2 coordinates x and y. How can something like Z which is part of 3d be represented by just 2 vectors X and Y? Is it because 'Z' and the 4th dimension vector here are not actually in 3d or 4d as they are in real life but are just some vectors that are restricted to two dimensions like the x and y component?

Comment: Hopefully someone will give you detailed answer, but meanwhile, I'll give you two examples to think about. When you take a (2D) photo of a 3D object, what's happening, mathematically? Vectors in three-dimensional space are being _projected_ onto a two-dimensional plane. This happens to be a linear transformation, so you can actually represent it by a matrix. And the order of the matrix will be $2 \times 3$. Here is a simple example of a projection: $f(x, y, z) = (x, y)$ (with $f \colon \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$). Try to express this as matrix multiplication, by taking the tuples as vectors.

Comment: In the other direction, you can also _embed_ a two-dimensional vector into three-dimensional space. That is, the photo that you took, although in itself two-dimensional (ideally), still exists in our three-dimensional reality. So you can map the vectors in the plane of the photograph to vectors in three-dimensional space, and then of course it will have three components, not two. For example, consider $g(x,y) = (x, y, 0)$ (with $g \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$). Express this using matrix multiplication too.

Comment: But more generally, you can have much more complicated maps than the ones in these examples. For instance, $h(x, y) = (y, 2x - 5y, x + 4y)$. It's true that the original vector has no $z$-component, but the transform does. But your intuition is correct to this extent: If you take the set of all the vectors you can obtain using this transformation (that is, the image of this function), they will only form a two-dimensional subspace of three-dimensional space! So in some sense, they _are_ missing a $z$-component (only, in different basis).

Comment: When you learn the formal definitions of dimension (of a vector space) and rank (of a matrix/transformation), you will see that indeed, a linear transformation cannot map from a lower dimensional subspace _onto_ a higher dimensional one (i.e., such a mapping cannot be surjective). If you map from an $n$-dimensional space (using a linear transformation), then the image has dimension less than or equal to $n$. And similarly, when you map from a higher dimensional space to a lower dimensional one, the map is necessarily non-injective (and the _nullity_ tells you exactly how non-injective it is).

Comment: Why don't know use the idea of matrix derived from simultaneous equations, you will find multiplication quite easy there

Comment: @M.Vinay So a 2x3 matrix is a 3 dimensional matrix whose z component has been 'squashed' to 0?

Comment: @M.Vinay I am confused by a few things.

You had said that 'a linear transformation cannot map from a lower dimensional subspace onto a higher dimensional one', but you had mentioned earlier that two dimensional photo can exist in our 3d world. Wouldnt going by what you said about linear transformations not being mappable froma  lower dimension to higher dimension mean that this 2d object cannot exist in our universe?

Comment: @M.Vinay  

In 'If you map from an n-dimensional space (using a linear transformation), then the image has dimension less than or equal to n', does it mean a higher dimension matrix being transformed by a lower dimensional or viceversa?

And in 'when you map from a higher dimensional space to a lower dimensional one, the map is necessarily non-injective (and the nullity tells you exactly how non-injective it is). ', what exactly does it mean? what does injective and nullity mean in this context? I amn't able to understand the definitions on the web, it seems to be something about sets?

Comment: @Hash A $2\times3$ matrix is not exactly one whose component is squashed, but one that _squashes_ three components into two. You need to think of matrices as _functions_ that maps vectors to vectors (in a "linear" manner, whatever that means). So rather than matrices having $x$, $y$, and $z$, components, they _act_ on the components of vectors. Now, in the first example I gave, indeed the function squashes the $z$ component of the vector entirely. But it's possible to "squash three components into two" in a less simplistic way. For example: $f(x, y, z) = (x + z, y - z)$.

Comment: @Hash The word "onto" is very important there. I use it in the formal sense of "surjective". What this means is, for example, if $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ is a linear transformation (i.e., a function defined as multiplying a particular matrix to all vectors), then the image of $f$ can never be the whole of the codomain $\mathbb R^3$. If you're not sure of what surjective, injective, etc. mean, I suggest taking the time to understand that first. Yes, these are concepts applicable to any set functions (not just linear transformations).

Comment: @Hash For example, consider two sets $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{x, y\}$. Define two functions $f$ and $g$ from $A$ to $B$ as follows: $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = x$, and $g(1) = g(2) = x$, $g(3) = y$. Then $f$ is _not_ surjective. Why? Because the image of $f$ is the set $\{x\}$, which is _not_ equal to the codomain $B$. (The image of a function is the set of all elements of the codomain that you can get by applying the function to all elements of the domain. Here, $\operatorname{image} f = \{f(1), f(2), f(3)\} = \{x, x, x\} = \{x\}$). But $g$ _is_ surjective, since its image is $\{x, y\} = B$.

Comment: When you have vector spaces and linear transformations, it's possible to meaningfully talk about dimensions (which you can't do when you only have sets and functions between sets). So $\mathbb R^2$ is two-dimensional, while $\mathbb R^3$ is three-dimensional (as you might expect) according to the formal definition of dimension [there's a technicality here about which "field" the space is defined over, but ignore that for now]. But a vector space can also have _subspaces_ (subsets that themselves form vector spaces with respect to the same vector operations).

Comment: So, $\mathbb R^3$ has many $2$-dimensional subspaces (such as the $x$-$y$ plane, the $x$-$z$ plane, the $y$-$z$ plane, and many others [any plane containing the origin]). And $1$-dimensional subspaces (the $x$-axis, etc., and others [any line containing the origin]). And a $0$-dimensional subspace, which is just the singleton set containing the origin: $\{(0, 0, 0)\}$. What I meant earlier is, if $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ is any linear transformation, then the image of $f$ must be a $2$-, $1$-, or $0$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, and never the **whole** of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @M.Vinay 'What I meant earlier is, if f:R2→R3 is any linear transformation, then the image of f must be a 2-, 1-, or 0-dimensional subspace of R3, and never the whole of R3'

So this means that if we attempt to convert a 2d  matrix into a 3d matrix by transforming it, the resulting matrix will only ever be in the 2d subsapces of R3 ,never the whole of R3 itself?

Comment: @Hash If, by "2d matrix" and "3d matrix", you mean _vectors_ of lengths $2$ and $3$ respectively, then yes, that's what I mean. If you multiply all vectors of order $2 \times 1$ by a fixed $3 \times 2$ matrix, the set of $3 \times 1$ vectors you'll get are going to form a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. You can never get all the vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ like this (by using a _single_ $3 \times 2$ matrix).

Comment: @M.Vinay If one multiplied a 3x2 matrix with a 2x1 matrix, the elements in the first row of the second matrix will eventually be multiplied with the 1st column of the second matrix right?
Now the first matrix has 2 components x and y, each with x y and z coordinates. The second matrix has one component with 2 coordinates. So, when multiplying 1st with 2nd matrix, wont we have to multiply z coordinates of components of first matrix with that of the 2nd matrix's elements?

So we are multiplying a 3d coordinate with the 2d coordinates in 2nd matrix? Wont that make the resultant matrix 3d also?

Comment: Firstly, it's not quite correct to think of matrix entries as _being_ $x$, $y$, $z$ components. They are components of the _action_ of the matrix on the components of any vector that it's being multiplied with. I'm not sure from what you wrote if that distinction was clear to you. That said, the answer to your question is both yes and no. It _is_ true that the resultant vector will be a vector _in_ 3D space. And if you're only considering a single vector, then that's all you can say too. But now if you vary the input (2D) vector to all possible 2D vectors, will you get _all_ 3D vectors? No.

Comment: You will only get a proper subset (in fact, a proper _subspace_) of the set of all 3D vectors. That space will have dimension $2$ or $1$ or $0$. (For example, consider multiplying by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. This defines a function $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ that maps each $(x, y)$ to $(x, 0, 0)$. So the image of the function (the set of all $\mathbb R^3$-vectors that you can get by multiplying $\mathbb R^2$-vectors by this matrix) is the $x$-axis in $\mathbb R^3$, which is a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: @M.Vinay So when mapping (x,y) to (x,a,b) , the result can be  2 vectors that can be in 3 dimensions , or 2 or 1 or 0 depending on the values of x, y , a and b, but no matter what we do, it will never encompass all of 3d space? And it will never return us a vector with the coordinates (x,a,b) ever?

also here, are x, a and b the columns of some matrix that is transforming (x,y) or is it something else?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the result can be 2 vectors". Each vector $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ gets mapped (by a $3 \times 2$ matrix) to a unique vector $(u, v, w)$ in $\mathbb R^3$, which is a three-dimensional vector space. And yes, no matter what the matrix is, once you fix it, you can never get _all_ the vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ even if you choose all possible $(x, y)$ as input.

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by "never return us a vector with coordinates $(x, a, b)$". First of all, note that a function of this sort defined by a matrix (that is, a linear transformation), can only map each $(x, y)$ to a vector $(u, v, w)$ where $u$, $v$, and $w$ are _linear combinations_ of $x$ and $y$ – which means they cannot be non-zero constants [$0$ is okay, because it can be considered as the linear combination $0x + 0y$].

Comment: So that also answers your last question: $u$, $v$, and $w$ are not columns of a matrix, they're linear combinations of $x$ and $y$. But it's true that the _coefficients_ of these linear combinations will come from the matrix you use. That is, if the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2\\b_1 & b_2\\c_1 & c_2\end{bmatrix}$, then $u = a_1 x + a_2 y$, $v = b_1 x + b_2 y$, and $w = c_1 x + c_2 y$. That follows immediately from matrix multiplication, because we're defining $\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: 'where u, v, and w are linear combinations of x and y'

here, this means that u v and w are the values/elements we get if we transform/multiply  (x,y) by a 3x2 vector right? 

'which means they cannot be non-zero constants' Is the reason they cant be non-zero constants because theyre represented by x+y and x and y are variables so u,v,w will be variables as well?

And the coefficients for these linear combinations come from the different values in the 3x2 matrix like a1,a2,b1,b2, etc right?

Comment: That's right. $u$, $v$, and $w$ will be linear combinations of $x$ and $y$. A linear combination of $x$ and $y$ is an expression of the form $ax + by$, for some constants $a$ and $b$. So yeah, $ax + by$ will not be constant unless $a = b = 0$, so then $ax + by = 0$ as well. [Note: Obviously, for each _particular_ values of $x$ and $y$, $ax + by$ is a constant. But as a function, $ax + by$ cannot be equal to, say, $3$, independent of the values of $x$ and $y$. Unlike a general set function, where we could very well define $f(x, y) = 3$ for all $x$, $y$].

Comment: And yes, the coefficients come from the matrix. You can see that the coefficients of the linear combination that defines the $i$-th component of the transformed vector [e.g., $(u, v, w)$, in the example I gave] come from the $i$-th row of the matrix. And in those coefficients, the coefficient of the $j$-th component of the input vector [e.g., $(x, y)$] will be the $j$-th entry of the $i$-th row of the matrix — i.e., its $(i, j)$-entry.

Comment: @M.Vinay 'the coefficients of the linear combination that defines the i-th component of the transformed vector [e.g., (u,v,w), in the example I gave] come from the i-th row of the matrix. And in those coefficients, the coefficient of the j-th component of the input vector [e.g., (x,y)] will be the j-th entry of the i-th row of the matrix — i.e., its (i,j)-entry. '

So essentially u is represented by i-th row i-th entry * x + i-th row j-th entry * y while v is represented by j-th row i-th entry * x + j-th row j-th entry * y and so on for w?

Comment: Yes. Well, the way to wrote it, you might as well have written first row first entry, first row second entry; second row first entry, second row second entry; etc. (The point of using $i$ and $j$ is to have generality). But I understand what you meant, and that's correct. You can see that by comparing the LHS and RHS in the definition of $(u, v, w)$ from $(x, y)$ by multiplication by a matrix.

Comment: Actually, long discussions in chat are pretty much discouraged here, and I shouldn't have given you (being a new user) the impression that this is normal. I was just too lazy to write a proper answer, and also thought you'd get better answers from others. Since that doesn't seem likely now, I'll (slowly) write an answer myself.

Comment: @M.Vinay My apologies, Im sorry I wasn't aware that long discussions were discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are a beginner to the subject. Well, you can't think multiplication between matrices as the multiplication with numbers. You know you can multiply any real number with another real number for instance, but this doesn't hold true between matrices. You can multiply a $n\times p$ matrix  $A$ with a $m\times q$ matrix $B$ if and only the number of columns of $A$ is equal to the number of rows of $B$, in other words $p=m$. This happens because of the definition of multiplication between matrices.

You said $A$ is $2\times4$ and $B$ $2\times2$, so you can't write $AB$ as $4\neq2$, but you can compute $BA$ which will be now a $2\times4$ matrix.

Comment: Yes I do know that. Sorry I had made a mistake with the AB being undefined. I still mix up which matrix's rows has to be equal to the other matrix's column when checking if their multiplication is valid. I struggle to intuitively understand the matching of columns and rows bit